# why setTimeout set to zero didn't put the code in a infinite recursive loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I get the following code form [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth) .This site tried to explain async callback functions and event loop in javascript.But i wonder why this line

```
timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0)
```

didn't create a recursive loop as it is executing without any delay.So settimeout will be invoked over and over again, So the following IF Statement will not execute .But in reality if statement gets executed.Why?

```
var i = 0, diff = 0, d = new Date()

var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  diff += new Date() - d
  timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0)
  if (i++==1000) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    alert("Resolution: "+diff/i)
  }
  d = new Date()
}, 0)
```

Comment: I don't get your question. What's the problem?

Comment: "without any delay" ain't entirely right. [more like 4-10ms minimum delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Nested_timeouts_forced_to_%3E4ms)

Comment: I suppose he means, that since he called setTimeout(), the timer function will get executed immediately, so the code never reaches the `if` statement. He basically asks, why the code hits the `if` statement.

Comment: The setTimeout invoked 1000 times, the if statement kicks in, clearTimeout stops the last setTimeout call (breaks the chain). What is not clear about this?

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous even when the delay is set to zero. There is no special rule for zero delay that would make it synchronous in that case.

Comment: @JakubJankowski yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

Javascript in Browsers single-threaded (because browsers use one thread for UI, as @vld commented). Any async operation (and setTimeout is one of them) will queue the code to be executed later. When the curren thread has finished (in this case at the line `d = new Date()`), the engine goes ahead and executes the code queued earlier, again in sequence and in a single thread. But since the timeout has been cleared by then, it will not execute again.

Comment: `Javascript is single-threaded.` More precisely, browsers use one thread for UI execution.